# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare casa_views_post_execute

Tags: debugging, emails

I understand this to be two declarations of the same function, which is not allowed. But how to fix this?

Everything was fine until I started to enable the MailChimp module, then the backend has this fatal error:

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare casa_views_post_execute() (previously declared in /home/kansascasa/public_html/sites/all/themes/casa/template.php:26) in /home/kansascasa/public_html/sites/all/themes/casa_m/template.php on line 80

This is the code:

```
    function casa_views_post_execute(&$view) {
    watchdog('theme', print_r($view->result[0], true));
  if ($view->name == 'programs2' && !empty($view->result)) {
    //drupal_goto('node/' . $view->result[0]->nid);
  }
}
```

Second one:

```
function casa_views_post_execute(&$view) {
```

}

What is the fix for this? Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have two separate themes. Perhaps the theme in the casa_m directory is a subtheme?

If the machine name of the theme in the /case_m/ directory is casa_m , then change the function name to casa_m_views_post_execute(&$view)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Thanks so much, I will try this.